# Change Windows 7 Wallpaper in C++

Tags: c++, windows, wallpaper

I saw someone at school who had a program that was supposed to change the background, and log you out (so the change would take effect) but it only worked on his computer, and he "lost" the source code. 
I have been looking online for a while for code that would do that, so I could experiment with it.

I found this code (C++)

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    SystemParametersInfo( SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (PVOID)"image.jpg", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE );
}
```

which *sort of* worked..

It worked twice with an image that was located in the same folder, and I tested two images, and after the second one it just stopped working.

I can't for the life of me figure out why it stopped working (I have tried multiple file extensions, so I know that isn't the issue).

I am working in Dev-C++, if that makes a difference to anyone.

Also, I would like to be able to modify the code to use a url instead of a local image...would that be possible?

Thanks!

Edit: If I change `image.jpg` to `image.bmp` it changes every time..But that means that it would only work with `*.bmp`? I had it working with a jpeg before.

Comment: Try Background Info http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557

Comment: If you specify a URL, you must download it first.

Comment: It appears to be working with any image currently, contrary to my last edit. Could you specify what you mean by downloading a url? As in the image that I want to set? I would like it to be able to take the image from the url itself so that I could use just the `*.exe` file on multiple computers without needing the `*.bmp` file located where the `*.exe` is located.

Comment: Try - PostMessage(GetDesktopWindow(), WM_SETTINGCHANGE, NULL, NULL);

Comment: @Desu_Never_Lies I put in that line, and it returned the error `9 C:\Users\CurrentUser\Desktop\Folder\main.cpp [Warning] passing NULL used for non-pointer converting 3 of 'BOOL PostMessageA(HWND__*, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)'`Is there something else that I have to do with that code?

Comment: Nope, it's just a warning, disregard it. (Even though I don't get how can it produce such a warning since W/LPARAM are both UINT_PTR, lol).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{   
 int i;
 for(i=0;;i++)
 {
  Sleep(800);
  if(i%2==0)
  {
   const wchar_t *filenm = L"C:\\Pictures\\image1.jpg"; //ADDRESS of first image
   bool isWallSet=SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0,(void*)filenm,SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);  
  }
  else
  {
   const wchar_t *filenm = L"C:\\Pictures\\image2.jpg"; //ADDRESS of second image
   bool isWallSet=SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0,(void*)filenm,SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);  
  }
 }
   return 0;
}
```